Hieroglyph3 HLSL Shader error X3004: undeclared identifier 'output'
I am trying to load this shader for a graphics programming project and keep getting this same error
The hlsl file is as follows
//---------------------------------

Texture2D DiffuseTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState TextureSampler : register(s0);

cbuffer Transforms
{
    matrix WorldMatrix;
    matrix ViewMatrix;
    matrix ProjMatrix;
};

//---------------------------------
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};


struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};



//----------------------------------
VS_OUTPUT VSMain(in VS_INPUT v)
{
    VS_OUTPUT o;

    float4 WorldSpace = mul(v.position, WorldMatrix);
    float4 ViewSpace = mul(WorldSpace, ViewMatrix);
    float4 ScreenSpace = mul(ViewSpace, ProjMatrix);

    o.position = ScreenSpace;
    o.color = v.color;

    output.tex = input.tex;

    return o;
}


//-----------------------------------
float4 PSMain(in VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    float4 sampledTextureColour = DiffuseTexture.Sample(TextureSampler, input.tex);
    return(sampledtexturecolour);
}

Does anyone know what exactly is causing this error?
Have been struggling to find any Heiroglyph3 resources online
Attempting to run heiroglpyh3 project to load a textured sphere using the above hlsl shader file but get error shown in picture

The problem is in VSMain():
output.tex = input.tex;
As the error message itself says, output is not declared anywhere. You probably meant o.tex.
Another problem you'll encounter even if you fix that is the use of input on the same line since it isn't declared either. You only declared it in PSMain(). I suspect the correct way to use it is
o.tex = v.tex;

Thank you so much, i will give that  a try, would you happen to know any good places for hlsl, heiroglyph 3 resources?

Unfortunately no. I don't have any shader programming background, just programming. But your error is not related to HLSL or Heiroglyph so it was easy for me to spot the error since it's common. I suggest you try regular C++ programming tutorials first, then jump to HLSL. What I do recommend is to be wary of where you do learn from. Not all tutorials teach you best practices, just "the easy ways". If the code above solves your issue, I suggest you mark it as accepted so it can help other people with similar issues that will find this post.

Gives me the same error but now with v, i changed the line to o.tex = v.tex; and the input in PS main to v.tex

@HarryButler21 Update the code in the question and post a new picture of the new error.

If you mean you changed v.tex here: float4 sampledTextureColour = DiffuseTexture.Sample(TextureSampler, input.tex); then you misunderstood what I wrote. There was no need. But if you did, either put it back or change float4 PSMain(in VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_Target to float4 PSMain(in VS_OUTPUT v) : SV_Target to fix it. As I said, these are programming issues, so my recommendation is to study and get better at programming first before jumping to shader programming. If you want to start simple, try Java or C#. The closest to HLSL is C++, but that might be harder for beginners.
